How to integrate swagger with spring 4.0 version?
I have a project with  <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version> and no spring-boot and I want to integrate swagger UI to it but whatever references I see they are for different version and mostly not helpful.
And none of the resources are on the same version and I am facing alot of difficulties.
So can somebody please tell me consolidated steps on how to proceed with the same. Or if anybody who has implemented the same, please guide me. I have been stuck on this from past week.

First, and I'm sure you know this, Spring 4.x has been out of support for almost 4 years ago now, and has known security vulnerabilities. That said, if there are reasons you have to use it, you should at least go to the very latest 4.x you can. (4.3.30-RELEASE)
If you're stuck at that version, we successfully used SpringFox 2.x with Spring 4 back before we updated to Spring 5 and SpringFox 3.
